# by SharedPreferences / Logcat error

Tags: java, android

i debugged my App and got this errorline:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.simonic.filmstudio.LogActivity$1.onClick(LogActivity.java:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4752)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19561)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`Log.Activity.java:42` is this row: `editor = sharedPrefs.edit();`

That is the rest of the Code:

```
package com.simonic.filmstudio;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LogActivity extends Activity {

//Buttons
Button startbutton;
//Variablen
EditText edtext;
String pname;
//Daten
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //Buttons
    startbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbutt);
    //EDTEXT
    edtext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText); //SpielerName
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Register Start Button

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edtext.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(100, 100, 100);
                String nopname = "@string/nopname";
                Toast.makeText(LogActivity.this, nopname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                pname = edtext.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("pname", pname);
                editor.putBoolean("regstat", true);
                editor.apply();
                startStudac();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void startStudac(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(LogActivity.this, StudioReg.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You are using sharedPrefs before assigning it anything. So it's null, hence the NullPointerException

To get the SharedPreferences reference, as you're inside an anonymous inner class you'll need to:

```
sharedPrefs = MyActivity.this.getSharedPreferences();
```

In your case:

```
sharedPrefs = LogActivity.this.getSharedPreferences();
```

As a suggestion, I'd made `sharedPrefs` and the preference editor local to that onClick() method as you're not using them in other parts of your Activity

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

instead of

```
String nopname = "@string/nopname";
```

write -

```
String nopname = "Simon";
```

**Solution 2 :**

In strings.xml file write:

```
<string name="nopname">Simon</string>
```

and in your activity class:

```
String nopname =  getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.nopname);
```

Comment: Yeah but in any other context for example Buttons in xml files etc. it works with "@string/nopname" ... I want to translate my App in other languages and therefore I have to do it with strings. 

Why does it not work with @string in this case ?

And can you help me with my main problem ? The shared Preferences ?